# Get the texts typed from keyboard (or custom keyboard)

Tags: android, security, caching

My question is that while we are typing text either they are email, passwords, credit card number all these are saved in device cache and shall we can fetch those typed texts from device cache?
Actually what I want to achieve is that to satisfy that my custom keyboard is secure and it does not saves the user typed texts to the device.
**But how to know that either keyboard saved texts or not?**

I have searched many website there is no clue that how to know that which keywords and how keyboard saving data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are really concerned about security then best option would be not to use custom keyboard.

In Android end keyboard or any data related transaction normally stores locally  in your same application cache if that custom keyboard would save anything out of application cache then app would ask you for the permissions which you can deny.

Although it is quiet possible to do low level keyboard hookup in Windows.
[Low level keyboard hook example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWHnhEZYTA0)

I hope it will satisfy your question.

Comment: You mean to say if we are useing any custom keyboard with in our application that means if and only if that custom keyboard stores any typed texts to cache that would be saved with in the application cache?

Comment: Then if its true that the custom keyboard stores texts with in application cache then I can read/get the  cache data? Can I?

Comment: Normal Keyboard doesn't save information anywhere in cache but like you said you have doubt your custom keyboard app might be saving data somewhere else.
So just in that case even if they would have cheated to save information they can't save out of application cache until you give permission to that keyboard app/widget..